# Cola con prioridad en java

Tags: java

Quisiera saber qué prioridad establece este ejercicio con cola de prioridad para que dé ese resultado, el resultado al sacar el elemento de la cabeza me da "querido". ¿Cómo se establece la prioridad? ¿El método `compareTo` tiene algo que ver?

```
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

class TestEx_c_ene14 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      PriorityQueue<Elemento> q = new PriorityQueue();
      String s[] = {"querido", "amigo", "hola", "feliz", "dosmilcatorce"};
      for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
       System.out.println(q.peek().toString());
     }
    }
    class Elemento implements Comparable<Elemento> {
      String atributo;
      public Elemento(String s) {
        atributo = s;
      }
     public String getAtributo() {
       return atributo;
     }
     public String toString() {
       return atributo;
     }
     public int compareTo(Elemento e) {
       int r = 0;
       if (e.getAtributo().length() < getAtributo().length())
         r = +1;
       else
        if (e.getAtributo().length() > getAtributo().length())
          r = -1;
     return r;
    }
}
```

Comment: *el resultado al sacar el elemento de la cabeza me da "querido"*: No. El código en la pregunta lanza un `NullPointerException` porque tu queue está vacío. No entiendo lo que se supone que tu código pretende mostrar.

Answer (score 1):

La función peek() utiliza el algoritmo FIFO (First in first out)
es decir que el primero en entrar es el primero en salir, en otras palabras siempre devolverá el primer elemento de la lista.

Para que la cola lo ordené de una manera especifica se le deben enviar dos parámetros al inicializarlo:

```
PriorityQueue(int capacidadInicial, Comparator<? super E> comparador)
```

En donde capacidadInicial es la capacidad que tendrá nuestra cola y el comparador es una clase que incluye el algoritmo de comparación como el siguiente ejemplo:

```
class PQsort implements Comparator<Integer> {  

public int compare(primitivo a, primitivo b){}

  public int compare(Integer primerElemento, Integer segundoElemento) {
      if(primerElemento > segundoElemento)
          return primerElemento;
      else
          return segundoElemento;
  }

}
```

Esa clase debe incluir una función llamada compare que devuelva el tipo de dato que debe comparar y debe pedir dos de esos tipos de datos.

Comment: ya pero lo que me dices es un cola sin prioridad, pero en este ejercicio es una priorityqueue. Puede ser que se estableca la prioridad con el metodo comparableTo? No se si me podeis echar una mano en eso.

Comment: @gabriel gomez, la respuesta esta correcta a la pregunta que haces, si deseas puedes hacer otra pregunta para el problema que tienes.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que te falta llenar la cola de elementos... De todas maneras puedes utilizar el constructor que recibe el comparator y lo modificas a tu antojo... como por ejemplo:

```
PriorityQueue<Elemento> q = new PriorityQueue(new Comparator<Elemento>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Elemento o1, Elemento o2) {
                int r = 0;
                if(o1.getAtributo().length() > o2.getAtributo().length()){
                    r = 1;
                }else if (o1.getAtributo().length() < o2.getAtributo().length()){
                    r = -1;
                }
                return r;
            }
        });
```

Si luego iteras mostrandolo por consola obtendras esto:

```
hola
feliz
amigo
querido
dosmilcatorce
```

Espero te sirva de algo!