# Agregar objetos a un ArrayList según orden de prioridad

Tags: java, arraylist

Hola estoy simulando una cola/pila de un hospital, la idea es ir atendiendo a los pacientes según su prioridad, se les asigna un numero de prioridad de manera manual y se agregan al ArrayList, de forma aleatoria se decide si se atiende al paciente o se encola/apila, mientras mayor sea el numero asignado mayor es su prioridad, es decir si a un paciente se le agrega el numero 7 y a otro el numero 3 se atenderá primero el numero 7, mi duda esta en el método que encola/apila a los pacientes.

```java
public void enqueue(String name, byte priority){
        Patient paciente = new Patient(name, priority);

        if(colaPacientes.isEmpty()){
            colaPacientes.add(paciente);
        } else {

            Patient pacienteGuardado;

            for(int i = 0; i < colaPacientes.size(); i++){
                pacienteGuardado = this.colaPacientes.get(i);
                if(paciente.prioridad >= pacienteGuardado.prioridad){
                    colaPacientes.add(i,paciente);
                } else {
                    colaPacientes.add(i,paciente);
                }
        }
    }
}
```

```java
public class Patient {
    String nombre;
    byte prioridad;

    public Patient (String nombre, byte prioridad){
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.prioridad = prioridad;
    }

    public String toString(){
        String display = nombre + ":" + Byte.toString(prioridad);
        return display;
    }
}
```

pues no se como encolar a los pacientes que llegan con menor prioridad, tengo confusión en como recorrer el ArrayList y ponerlos en el lugar que les corresponde según su prioridad.

Ya que cuando agrego 2 pacientes la consola me tira el siguiente error:

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap
>   space"

Me pueden ayudar con alguna idea de como hacerlo?

Comment: ¿Por qué mezclas los conceptos cola y pila? Son dos cosas diferentes y al parecer lo que estás usando es una cola, no una pila. Ahora, lo que quieres hacer es tener ordenado tu ArrayList de mayor a menor, si es así, puedes usar el método [sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)) de la clase [Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html)

Comment: Es absolutamente necesario usar una `ArrayList`? En específico, yo usaría `TreeSet` en este caso.

Comment: También ayudaría conocer la implementación de `Patient` porque cuando quieres ordenar una lista de objetos, es importante saber cómo está implementado su método `equals` y posiblemente su método `compareTo` si es que implementa `Comparable`.

Comment: @MrDave1999 porque esi es el comportamiento, si llega un paciente con prioridad alta es el primero en ser atendido y si agrega al inicio de la cola, ósea se apila, pero si llega alguien con una prioridad baja se manda al final de la cola, ósea se encola, no se si te queda claro...

Comment: @DavidDPG en el requerimiento de la simulación así lo establecen, voy agregar Patient para que lo veas, peor solo crea un objeto.

Answer (score 0):

En ese caso debe de utilizar colas implementadas en java pero con el algoritmo de planificación según prioridad de la siguiente manera.

Para que la cola lo ordené de una manera especifica se le deben enviar dos parámetros al inicializarlo:

```
PriorityQueue(int capacidadInicial, Comparator<? super E> comparador)
```

En donde capacidadInicial es la capacidad que tendrá nuestra cola y el comparador es una clase que incluye el algoritmo de comparación como el siguiente ejemplo:

```
class PQsort implements Comparator<Integer> {  

public int compare(primitivo a, primitivo b){}

  public int compare(Integer primerElemento, Integer segundoElemento) {
      if(primerElemento > segundoElemento)
          return primerElemento;
      else
          return segundoElemento;
  }

}
```

Esa clase debe incluir una función llamada compare que devuelva el tipo de dato que debe comparar y debe pedir dos de esos tipos de datos

Link del post referencias: [Cola con prioridad en java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42603/cola-con-prioridad-en-java)

la respuesta no es de mi autoria.
Saludos

Comment: No puedo dejar comentario aún, solo respuesta, para la próxima la aplicó, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Usando forzosamente un ArrayList, lo mejor que se me ocurre es recorrer la lista (ordenada de mayor a menor prioridad) y cuando encuentres una posición en la que la prioridad del paciente a insertar sea mayor o igual, insertar ahí:

```
public void enqueue(Patient newPatient) {
    if (this.patients.isEmpty()) {
        this.patients.add(newPatient);
        return;
    } else if (this.patients.size() == 1 && this.patients.get(0).getPriority() <= newPatient.getPriority()){
        patients.add(newPatient);
        return;
    } else {
        int enqueuingIndex = 0;
        for (Patient patient : patients) {
            if (patient.getPriority() <= newPatient.getPriority()) {
                patients.add(enqueuingIndex, newPatient);
                return;
            } else {
                enqueuingIndex++;
            }
        }
    }
    patients.add(patients.size(), newPatient);
}
```

Que quede claro que **no recomiendo esta solución en una situación real**, se te simplificaría mucho la vida, y seguiría mucho más los principios de POO si `Paciente` implementase `Comparable` y usaras un `TreeSet`.